# Variable SQL query from $wpdb->get_results escapes ampersand so doesn't return any results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**EDIT: I've found the cause but not the solution. By using var_dump($wpdb->last_query), I've found that it's escaping the ampersand to `R&#038;D`, so the query (correctly) no longer returns any results:**

```
SELECT `user_id`  FROM `wp_usermeta` LEFT JOIN `intranet_skills` on `skill_indicator` = `meta_value` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-skills' AND `Skill_description` LIKE 'R&#038;D'
```

**How do I I avoid it doing that?**

---

I'm trying to return query results from `$wpdb` using a generated SQL query, as I'm constructing a template page which will be used multiple times. The constructed query doesn't return any results, even though the query itself is (to my eyes) valid.

My PHP is...

```
global $wpdb;

$super_user_title = str_ireplace(array("superusers","super users","superuser","super user","super-user","super-users",'MS ','experts','expert'),"", get_the_title() );

$super_user_sql = "SELECT `user_id`  FROM `$wpdb->usermeta` LEFT JOIN `intranet_skills` on `skill_indicator` = `meta_value` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-skills' AND `Skill_description` LIKE '%$super_user_title%'";

$super_user_query = $wpdb->get_results($super_user_sql);
```

The page in question is called R&D, so I suspect that the ampersand may be causing an issue. It works on all the other pages, just not this one.

However, if I `echo` the variable `$super_user_sql` and use that directly, it works fine.

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` LEFT JOIN `intranet_skills` on `skill_indicator` = `meta_value` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-skills' AND `Skill_description` LIKE '%R&D%'");
```

The above returns the expected results correctly. `$wpdb->print_error();` and `$wpdb->last_error();` return nothing.

I've also tried preparing the query first, but that fails similarly.

```
$super_user_sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `user_id`  FROM `$wpdb->usermeta` LEFT JOIN `intranet_skills` on `skill_indicator` = `meta_value` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'wpcf-skills' AND `Skill_description` LIKE '%%%s%%'",$super_user_title);
```

What's up with that?

Comment: A similar question is asked here, but has no answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215374/wpdb-get-resultsquery-returns-null-with-variable-query-same-query-works?rq=1

Comment: Most likely your initial `&` is not an `&`, but `&amp;` - the HTML entity corresponding to the character `&`. Not sure if `get_the_title` does HTML escaping, it might also be one of the filters applied. So your query containing `WHERE foo = 'R&amp;D'` finds nothing. When you echo the content of your variable, your browser interprets it as HTML - so it _displays_ `&amp;` as `&`, and what you then copy actually _is_ an `&`. So either go find a function that gets you the original page title (without any HTML escaping), or reverse it before you put the value into the query.

Comment: I've temporarily solved it by changing all of the & in the MySql table to `&#038;`, but would like a proper solution that avoids this so will keep the question open.

Comment: Not sure if that is a solution at all - because if WP applies HTML escaping, then you would end up with `R&amp;D` _displayed_ on the site (because the `&amp;` from the database gets encoded again). I’d rather try and use `html_entity_decode` before inserting the value into the query.

Comment: @CBroe - Oh, it's a band-aid to be sure, but the actual value `R&#038;` isn't displayed on the site so it's not a huge problem